# Multiple *ngFor loops in ion-list

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have two arrays of data. "subtitles" & "title". How to I properly incorporate the two arrays into an ion-list, so that I have a title and subtitle from the two arrays showing in one ion-item (title on top of the subtitle)?

in my .ts file:

```ts
items = [
 'Email',
 'Phone Number',
 'Address',
 'Cards'
];

data = [ 
  "first last",
  "test phone number",
  "test address"
]
```

in my .html file

```html
<ion-content padding>
 <ion-list class="list">
  <div *ngFor="let unit of data">
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="enterPage(item)">
        {{item}}
        {{unit}}
   </button>
  </div>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: If you expecting array `data` to have same amount of items like array `items` you can add index to `*ngFor`(let i = index), remove second loop and change `{{item}}` to `{{items[i]}}`

Comment: Ah I see what you are saying. What if they don't have the same amount?

Comment: If the **items** is always longer than the **data**, then make **ngfor statement** for the **items** and try @Buczkowski's way with **ngIf**. It will not make the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index" (click)="enterPage(item)">
        {{items[i]}}
        <h3>{{data[i]}}</h3>
  </button>
```